# Re-order the rows in Woocommerce Basket

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce and I need to display the current shipping method and price that's selected after the shipping "Update Totals" button.

So, I need to display:

- Sub Total
- Shipping drop down selector and postcode/zipcode options
- "Update Totals" button
- **THE SHIPPING METHOD AND PRICE**
- VAT if applicable
- Grand Total

How can I achieve this?

Here's a screen-shot to help demonstrate:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a child theme to your theme. https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203105897-How-to-set-up-and-use-a-child-theme.
2. Create in your child theme a in same loaction file duplicate of woocommerce --> temapltes --> cart --> cart-shipping.php
3. Change the order of lines in files.
4. That should work, and wordpress will run the file in child-theme with the changes instead of original one.

Comment: Ok thanks although still lost, have tried to move what I thought I should, but it keeps breaking, anyone any ideas on how this should look

Comment: This stupid box, won't let me paste what I moved! I grabbed the whole section that dealt with the displaying of the chosen method, but the whole basket sections topped working